# Mockito is not working for me

Tags: java, rest, mockito, junit4

Case 1: Below  call in my service class where Employee is only class

```
ResponseEntity<Employee> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity,Employee.class);
```

Below is used in my test class , response is giving emp object.

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
ResponseEntity<Employee> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<Employee>(emp,HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
when(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(),Mockito.<Class<Employee>>any())).thenReturn(responseEntity);
```

Case 2: Below  call in my service class where Employee is  array

```
ResponseEntity<Employee[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity,Employee[].class);
```

I am using below in my junit test. but getting response as null.

```
ResponseEntity<Employee[]> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<Employee[]>(emp,HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
when(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(),Mockito.<Class<Employee[]>>any())).thenReturn(responseEntity);
```

In case (1) I am using `Employee` whereas in case (2) I am using `Employee[]`. when `Employee[]` is used in my service and test I am getting `null response(ResponseEntity obj)` but when I use `Employee` only in service and test then I am getting ResponseEntity object with emp(stubbed or dummy).

Please help out on this why I am getting null in case (2).

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

```
ResponseEntity<Employee[]> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<Employee[]>(emp,HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
when(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(),Mockito.<Class<Employee[]>>anyObject())).thenReturn(responseEntity);
```